# Set integer range for primefaces selectonemenu values

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to show continuous integer values from a certain min value to max value.

Is there any way of looping from min to max on xhtml page and add loop values to selectItems

Currently I am doing as:

```
<p:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.intValuesFrom25ToMaxValue}" var="myInteger" itemValue="#{myInteger}" itemLabel="#{myInteger}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

**NOTE:** There is no problem with current solution, but I have a lot of different select one menus whose values are just a continuous range of integers, so for all of the I have to write getter functions? Thats why I want to create a loop on xhtml page.

Comment: What is the problem with your solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with

```
 <ui:repeat value="#{bean.yourInts}" var="oneInt">
      <f:selectItem value="#{oneInt}" />
 </ui:repeat>
```

I hope it's correct, I have no chance to try it right now:-)

**EDIT**

In that case try this

```
 <c:forEach begin="25" end="100" var="i">
     <f:selectItem value="#{i}" />     
 </c:forEach>
```

It's not a perfect solution because you are mixing JSTL with JSF (which sometimes causes problem) but in this case is fine because your loop does not use any dynamic values.

Comment: I don't want to load from backing bean, since I know min max integer range, I want to loop from min to max on xhtml page

Comment: ,c:foreach function works fine when I give begin and end values here. But it is not working if I pass end value from bean. Is it so or I am missing some other thing?

Comment: You said you don't need it:)But try using ${bean.maxValue} instead of #{bean.maxValue}